# Android Studio 3.1.2 Run button not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3

Android Studio 3.1.2 Run button enabled. But when click on run button no action happened.

I restarted android studio and my windows 10 also. But still Run button click not showing anything.﻿

[image]

Comment: Have you checked whether your gradle is still building? Also, try to "build project".

Comment: no gradle build finished successfully..

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

- There's a **Run** option on the menu, locate it and click on it.
- Click on Edit Configurations
- Click on Android Application on the left side and then click the + button.
- Choose Android Application from the pop-up menu. Then pick the module (app). Then click apply and then Ok.

If this doesn't work, try re-importing the project into Android Studio, that should fix the problem.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: Thank's for your support. But still the same issue. I submit the bug report to android-studio.

Comment: Have you tried re-importing the project back into android studio?

Comment: I re-imported my project. & still not working.. I imported another projects to check. But Same issues occured.

Comment: I tried all of this & it's not working....
I removed android studio. Now I installing it again.
& Now I'm working on my another laptop..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already solved it, but I got the same issue and found a solution. For me the problem was that adb wasn't found. After reinstalling platform-tools it got solved.

So try opening SDK Manager from Tools -> SDK Manager, go to SDK Tools tab and uncheck Android SDK Platform-Tools. After applying changes install it again.

Comment: Hi @Shadow. It is explained avobe just from Android Studio go to Tools -> SDK Manager, then uninstall Android SDK Platform-Tools and after that install it again. That's it.

The point is that this might happen for multiple reasons, for example you can also have Android Support plugin disabled. Nevertheless Android Studio will warn you about it.

This was what happened to me particularly

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled android studio. Make sure that you delete every possible file, I manually deleted a few files after uninstalling android studio (yes not all files get deleted when you uninstall and specifically user settings). Then download again the .exe from their official website, it will ask you whether to import settings from the previous version, select no. And download all dependencies (make sure you have a good access to internet) and there you go!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. `adb.exe` was deleted from `platform-tools` folder and error was

> "Unable to locate adb java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to
>   locate adb" .

Just copy paste `adb.exe` into `platform-tools` folder and run again it works perfectly..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have anti-virus try to disable it and check if `adb-file.exe` is deleted or quarantined by it.

in my case `Avast` was stopping the android studio from running